# Uploading a string with progress not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I use jQuery to upload a random generated payload:

```
    var promise = new jQuery.Deferred();
    var uploadStartTime;

$.ajax({
    url: '/Api/HeartBeat/UploadSpeedTest',
    data: { '': self.payload },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    timeout: 10000,
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function () {
        uploadStartTime = new Date();
    },
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                console.log(percentComplete);
            }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
}).done(function (e) {
    var diff = Math.abs((new Date()) - uploadStartTime);
    var speed = Math.round(e.AmountReceived / diff);
    console.log('upload test successful. Payload: ' + e.AmountReceived + 'B. Required speed: ' + e.RequiredUploadSpeed + 'KB/s. Download time: ' + diff + 'ms. Actual speed: ' + speed + 'KB/s');
});
```

Where `self.payload` is a 100kb generated random, base64 encoded, string.

When I run this the progress is immediatly 100%, `evt.loaded` and `evt.total` are equal. When I simulate a 5kb/s connection with Fiddlr it will hang for 20 seconds on 100% and never progresses.

Is this a bug in Chrome or is my implementation wrong?

These are the sent headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:99937
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Host:host.domain.com
Origin:http://host.domain.com
Referer:http://host.domain.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (pattern)

```
// progressObj = {"now" : "", "then" : ""};
// add other metrics / properties to `progressObj`
$(document)
.on("ajaxStart", function () {
    console.log("starting at " + $.now())
    // progressObj.now = $.now(); 
    // process other metrics / properties of `progressObj`
 })
.on("ajaxStop", function () {
    console.log("done at " + $.now());
    // progressObj.then = $.now(); 
    // process other metrics / properties of `progressObj`
    // console.log(progressObj)
});
```